# How to verify my dynamic optimization results graphically, comparing with initial conditions in gekko

Tags: python, gekko

Good morning friends and Professor Hedengren, I am new to Python and even more to Gekko, first of all, I would like to know if my code in Gekko is correct, that is, according to what I physically want, considering that my equations are correct.

My model tries to optimize the variables `M2` and `l_M2` (or the combination of these 2 variables), in order to minimize in module the amplitude of movement (positive or negative) of my variable `q1`, my model receives inputs from the placed text file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DwSW93XoOdgpZGWXYRsrrHVXGQ6fq2U-/view?usp=sharing), the model solution must respect the following:

- With the initial values ​​of `M2` and `l_M2`, the model is solved and the maximum amplitude (positive or negative) of `q1` is obtained;
- The input values ​​do not vary over the horizon;
- In each iteration the value of the variable `c_m2` must be updated according to the value of `M2` and `l_M2`, and it must remain constant throughout the horizon.

In order to minimize the variable `q1` I proposed two types of objectives, which I do not use simultaneously:

- Minimize `1000*q1**2`;
- Minimize the integral of `x1 = integral (0.5 q1 ** 2)` dt evaluated from 0 to t, for which create an auxiliary variable `x1`.

**Doubts to solve**

- When solving the model, I realized that the value of `c_m2` (at the initial point) is 0. Which is not correct, as it should be the same value as the following, so there is an error in my code , which I don't know. How to solve;
- On the other hand, I would like to be able to compare the responses of the model with the initial values ​​of the variables versus the response with the optimized values ​​(as shown in the figure), but I cannot understand how to save my response with the initial values.
  [Optimization check figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwfVv.png)
- Is it correct to use `m.options.IMODE = 6` in this case?

this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

###################### CREATION OF LOAD RECORD
filename= 'Inputs 0.02sec.txt'
input_l=(np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1, dtype=float).flatten()).tolist()
dt=0.02

len_inputs=len(input_l)

m=GEKKO()

# time vector
t_final=dt*(len_inputs-1)
m.time=np.linspace(0, t_final, len_inputs)

# parameters
M1=m.Param(value=21956548.3771968)
Ri=m.Param(value=10609404.1758615)
taxa1=m.Param(value=0.02)
taxa2=m.Param(value=0.005)
grv=m.Param(value=9.80665)
in_loads=m.Param(value=input_l)

m.options.NODES = 4
m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC

#Intermedias
Om1=m.Intermediate(m.sqrt(Ri/M1))
C_M1=m.Intermediate(2*M1*Om1*taxa1)

# variables
M2=m.FV(value=0.10*21956548.3771968,lb=0.01*M1 , ub=0.20*M1)
M2.STATUS = 1
l_M2=m.FV(value=7, lb=1, ub=20)
l_M2.STATUS = 1
c_m2=m.Var(value=2*taxa2*M2*m.sqrt(grv/l_M2))
x1=m.Var(value=0)           # auxiliar variable for integral of   x1=0.5*integral(q1**2)dt
q1=m.Var(value=0)
q1_p=m.Var(value=0)
q2=m.Var(value=0)
q2_p=m.Var(value=0)

# auxiliar equation for minimization of integral of x1=0.5*integral(q1**2)dt
m.Equation(x1.dt()==0.5*(q1**2))

# equations for actualization of c_m2
m.Equation(c_m2==2*taxa2*m.sqrt(grv/l_M2))

# equations of state
m.Equation(q1.dt()==q1_p)
m.Equation(q1_p.dt()==((-Ri*q1-C_M1*q1_p+M2*grv*q2+(c_m2*q2_p)/l_M2) \
                       /M1-in_loads))
m.Equation(q2.dt()==q2_p)
m.Equation(q2_p.dt()==(Ri*q1+C_M1*q1_p-(M1+M2)*grv*q2)/(l_M2*M1) \
                        -c_m2*(M1+M2)*q2_p/(M1*M2*l_M2**2))


m.Obj(1000*q1**2)       # for minimization of q1  (1000*q1**2)
# m.Obj(x1)             # for minimization of integral 0.5*q1**2


m.solve()

######################################### Plotting the results
fig=plt.figure(1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax4.plot(m.time, q1.value, ls='-', label=f'q1 Opt')
ax4.set_ylabel('Amplitude of q1 [m]')
ax4.set_xlabel('Time [sec]')
ax4.set_title('Time - Amplitude \n')
ax4.legend(loc='best')
plt.grid()

minimo,maximo=min(q1.value),max(q1.value)
Max_q1=max(abs(minimo),abs(maximo))

# print results
print ('')
print ('--- Results of the Optimization Problem ---')
print ('M2= ' + str(M2.value))
print ('l_M2 = ' + str(l_M2.value))
print ('c_m2 = ' + str(c_m2.value))
print ('Absolute Max Amplitude q1= ', Max_q1)
print ('Percentage of massa m2= ' + str(M2.value[-1]/M1.value[-1]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: There is the `m.integral(0.5 q1**2)` function if it is easier to use this to define your problem. Also, try using `m.Minimize()` instead of `m.Obj()` to improve the readability.

Answer (score 1):

Nice work on this application. Everything that you described looks correct. The `c_m2` value is zero at the beginning because initial conditions are fixed at the specified values (or default 0) and equations are not solved at `t=0`.

Try using two `m.solve()` commands with the first one with `m.options.COLDSTART=1` (temporarily sets `STATUS=0`) to see the initial and optimized solution.

```py
m.options.COLDSTART = 1
m.solve()

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax4.plot(m.time, q1.value, ls='-', label=f'q1 Initial')

m.options.COLDSTART = 0
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
m.solve()

ax4.plot(m.time, q1.value, ls='-', label=f'q1 Opt')
ax4.set_ylabel('Amplitude of q1 [m]')
ax4.set_xlabel('Time [sec]')
ax4.set_title('Time - Amplitude \n')
ax4.legend(loc='best')
```

[image: Initial and Optimal]

Here is the full script:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

###################### CREATION OF LOAD RECORD
filename= 'Inputs 0.02sec.txt'
input_l=(np.loadtxt(filename, skiprows=1, dtype=float).flatten()).tolist()
dt=0.02

len_inputs=len(input_l)

m=GEKKO()

# time vector
t_final=dt*(len_inputs-1)
m.time=np.linspace(0, t_final, len_inputs)

# parameters
M1=m.Param(value=21956548.3771968)
Ri=m.Param(value=10609404.1758615)
taxa1=m.Param(value=0.02)
taxa2=m.Param(value=0.005)
grv=m.Param(value=9.80665)
in_loads=m.Param(value=input_l)

m.options.NODES = 4
m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC

#Intermedias
Om1=m.Intermediate(m.sqrt(Ri/M1))
C_M1=m.Intermediate(2*M1*Om1*taxa1)

# variables
M2=m.FV(value=0.10*21956548.3771968,lb=0.01*M1 , ub=0.20*M1)
M2.STATUS = 1
l_M2=m.FV(value=7, lb=1, ub=20)
l_M2.STATUS = 1
c_m2=m.Var(value=2*taxa2*M2*m.sqrt(grv/l_M2))
x1=m.Var(value=0)           # auxiliar variable for integral of   x1=0.5*integral(q1**2)dt
q1=m.Var(value=0)
q1_p=m.Var(value=0)
q2=m.Var(value=0)
q2_p=m.Var(value=0)

# auxiliar equation for minimization of integral of x1=0.5*integral(q1**2)dt
m.Equation(x1.dt()==0.5*(q1**2))

# equations for actualization of c_m2
m.Equation(c_m2==2*taxa2*m.sqrt(grv/l_M2))

# equations of state
m.Equation(q1.dt()==q1_p)
m.Equation(q1_p.dt()==((-Ri*q1-C_M1*q1_p+M2*grv*q2+(c_m2*q2_p)/l_M2) \
                       /M1-in_loads))
m.Equation(q2.dt()==q2_p)
m.Equation(q2_p.dt()==(Ri*q1+C_M1*q1_p-(M1+M2)*grv*q2)/(l_M2*M1) \
                        -c_m2*(M1+M2)*q2_p/(M1*M2*l_M2**2))

m.Minimize(1000*q1**2)       # for minimization of q1  (1000*q1**2)

m.options.COLDSTART = 1
m.solve()

fig=plt.figure(1)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax4.plot(m.time, q1.value, ls='-', label=f'q1 Initial')

m.options.COLDSTART = 0
m.options.TIME_SHIFT = 0
m.solve()

ax4.plot(m.time, q1.value, ls='-', label=f'q1 Opt')
ax4.set_ylabel('Amplitude of q1 [m]')
ax4.set_xlabel('Time [sec]')
ax4.set_title('Time - Amplitude \n')
ax4.legend(loc='best')

minimo,maximo=min(q1.value),max(q1.value)
Max_q1=max(abs(minimo),abs(maximo))

# print results
print ('')
print ('--- Results of the Optimization Problem ---')
print ('M2= ' + str(M2.value))
print ('l_M2 = ' + str(l_M2.value))
print ('c_m2 = ' + str(c_m2.value))
print ('Absolute Max Amplitude q1= ', Max_q1)
print ('Percentage of massa m2= ' + str(M2.value[-1]/M1.value[-1]))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Professor, a question please, I have a known optimum point and when I set it as the starting point for the variables `M2 = m.FV (value = 0.20 * 21956548.3771968, lb = 0.01 * M1, ub = 0.20 * M1)` and `l_M2 = m .FV (value = 13.2927529387356, lb = 1, ub = 20)` , the result is worse than the known optimum point, why is this happening? Is there any way to prevent me from getting this wrong result? or to return this same optimum point to me? the maximum results were: Absolute Max Amplitude q1 Opt = 0.22987254086
Absolute maximum amplitude q1 Initial conditions = 0.20725808504

Comment: On the other hand, when I start with initial conditions close to this known point, I cannot reach this optimal point and my result is therefore worse.

Comment: Are you trying to maximize q1? Try using `m.maximize()` instead of `m.Obj()` that minimizes. Also check that the constraints are satisfied at the initial guess.

Comment: no professor, I'm trying to **minimize the maximum amplitude of q1**, the initial conditions satisfy the constraints, but when solving, the **maximum value of q1 optimized** is greater than the **maximum value of the initial condition**, as I mentioned in my first comment, the only thing that I did, it was to modify the initial conditions of the two variables in the code that you put `M2 = m.FV (value = 0.20 * 21956548.3771968, lb = 0.01 * M1, ub = 0.20 * M1)` and `l_M2 = m .FV (value = 13.2927529387356, lb = 1, ub = 20)` . 
In advance professor, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The initial value of `M2` is the same as its upper limit.

Comment: Here is more information on maximin and minimax: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/MiniMax